# Bind an auto-clickable link in an image

Tags: image, image-processing, data-binding, hyperlink

For the marketing point of view, I wish to somehow bind an auto-clickable link in an image such that whenever the image is viewed/opened, the link should be clicked in background. Then we will later come to know from where the image is opened & how many users have seen our image. It would be done through google url shortner analytics.

Link should not be opened in browser but only clicked in background.

Looks like some hacking trick but we need it market our new logo.

Please let me know.